# Sum a python list without the string values

Tags: python

So according to duck-typing advice, you aren't advised to check types in python, but simply see if an operation succeeds or fails. In which case, how do I sum a list of (mainly) numbers, while omitting the strings.

```
sum([1,2,3,4,'']) #fails
sum(filter(lambda x: type(x)==int, [1,2,3,4,''])) #bad style
```

Comment: Why do you have strings mixed in with the numbers?

Comment: I guess that's the insightful question, because I'm essentially treating strings as 'missing data'. That of course leads to problems such as  sum(filter(lambda x: type(x)==int, ['','',''])) == 0, whereas it should be (say) None

Comment: If all the strings in your list are '', then you can use `sum([v for v in [1,2,3,4,''] if v])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do something like this

```
a = [1,2,3,4,'']
print sum(x if not isinstance(x,str) else 0 for x in a)
```

Comment: I selected this as the answer as it will cope even if there are (e.g.) floats in the list (although I know this wasn't in the original question).

Comment: I had that in my mind , that's why answered this way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I see two main solutions here:

- Pre-processing: Filter the input data in order to prevent occurrences of `'missing data'`, might be quite complex. We can't help you on this point without more informations.
- Post-processing: Filter the result list and remove `'missing data'`, easy but it isn't really scalable.

About post-processing, here is a solution using list comprehension, and another using your `filter`-based approach:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,'']
filtered_a = [x for x in t if isinstance(x, int)]
filtered_a = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), a)
```

Then, you can simply do `sum(filtered_a)`

We can also argue that you can check for data consistency during the processing, and just don't add string in your array.

Comment: The extra `[]`are not required in the `sum()`.

Comment: Thanks guys =D it's fixed !

Comment: The best approach is not to use type, but to use a isinstance calls. The pitfall of using type is that someone could subclass int in the future, and then your code won't work.  So +1 for that

Comment: Thanks. isinstance is probably better, yes. But it's still 'look before you leap', I guess.

Comment: Yeah - I'm probably better using None for missing data, then sum works nearly correctly, although this 'sum' equivalent is better (apologies for bad formatting)

    `def sensible_sum(l):
        '''Treat None as NA, e.g. if l==[] or l == [None, None] return None'''
        l = filter(lambda x: x is not None, l)
        return reduce(lambda x,y: (x or 0)+y, l, None)`